# Terminal does not exit and can not be drag or move

Tags: command-line, kubuntu

I'm using kubuntu 17.10 (with the default DE KDE)[image: SCREEN SHOT 1]
[image: SCREEN SHOT 2]

last night im using my terminal and suddenly my laptop freeze and when it comes back to life my terminal came to resize it self. Now it does not move or resize or exit it still setting there. I try to open another terminal window and it works normal. I try to shutdown/restart/log off my laptop nothing happen it still there. I even boot to different OS and come back is still there..

can anyone help me for this..

Comment: Did someone make fun of you, took a screenshot while the window was open and then put that screenshot as your background image? _(I admit, I already did such things... ;-))_

Comment: See https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2256778

Comment: I works...i follow your comments in ububtuforums.org.....I disable the terminal..

Answer (score 0):

See if this works,
In the command line type the following-

```
$ ps -A
```

A list of processes will be displayed along with a number which is their id process id. It might be something like this.

```
19982     ?        00:00:00 kworker/0:2
20019    tty2     00:00:43 chromium-browse
20034    tty2     00:00:01 chromium-browse
20081    ?        00:00:01 gnome-terminal-
20138    pts/1    00:00:00 bash
20176    pts/0    00:00:00 bash
20187    pts/0    00:00:00 ps
```

The 5 digit number on the left is the process id or pid,

In the command line type - `$ killall pid`

for example, The pID for the gnome-terminal from the above example is `20081`

Therefore, I am going to give the command - `$ killall 20081`

P.S. Killing a program using its process name, only works for executable files that are kept open during execution. Programs that run in the background cannot be killed using the process name.

Comment: I see only 4 digit number, like this one, 3013?   00:00:01 konsole

Comment: I see only 4 digit number, like this one, 3013?   00:00:01 konsole, and, ...killall 3013.......3013: no process found.  killall pid 3013,..pid: no process foound, 3013: no process found..

Comment: Instead of $ ps -A try this - $ ps  -u 'yourusername'

Comment: Then you get the same view of processes- type the command - $ kill -1 fourdigitnumber